# how to read row values of .xls file in Groovy/JAVA POI

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, groovy

How can i read a row values of a particular row in a .xls file.
Here in my example i am trying just to read a row of test8. How can i read this six values assigened to test8. Please help. Thank you.
Ps: In my code i am trying to read that row values and assign one value from it. I habe to aggign in my `def value = ""`

My code is.

```
        private void calculateweight(BBucket bucket, ZWorkbookImpl workbook) 
        {
            //find right row, extract data
        try {
            def testProgram = bucket.getTestProgram()
            workbook.goToSheet("Sheet2")
            workbook.goToPosition(0, 0)  //Searches for particular test program in the first column ex:Test8
            
                        while(true)
                        {
                            if(workbook.readCell(false).contentEquals(testProgram)) // Here it finds Test8, now how to get the values of row Test8 ??
                               {
                                workbook.goToNextCell()
                                der value = //Todo "read the values of particular row and take one value which fits"
                                container.getAll(new FilterAllDomainObjects()).each{e ->    
                                                                    e.setProgramExtension(value)
                                    //calculate program
                                    //Store program on the stent
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            workbook.goToNextRow(false)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Error parsing ${fileName} file", e)
                    }       
            
        }
```

[image: excel file]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027731/how-can-i-read-specific-rows-with-apache-poi does this help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read specific rows with Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027731/how-can-i-read-specific-rows-with-apache-poi)

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke Thank you for the refernce. I looked into it. In the refernce link it reads the cell from the first row and gets the value needed. How can i read a particular row when i already know which row values to be fetched from my Implementation logic. I am trying somehow to compare both and find a suitable logic to mine. Was not sucessful in getting it.